# What is the correct to way to loop request with axios and async await?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, async-await, axios

I have about 500 URLs that I want to loop and get data from, the URLs are stored inside a const name urls:

```
const urls = []
```

I want to do something like this:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= url.length; i++) {
  const response = await axios.get(url);
  responseList.push(response)
}
```

response list is another const that I have outside the for loop.

This is actually working, but eslint has a rule for "no-await-in-loop" which makes me think I'm not doing the more optimized thing here.

What would be the best practice in this case?

Comment: Ignore that rule. There is no point in doing 500 requests at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matia's answer with just a little edit, remember to return inside promises:

```
const promises = urls.map(url => return axios.get(url));
const response = await Promise.all(promises);
responseList.push(...response);
```

Otherwise promises will be a list of undefines.

Answer (score 0):

Actually [eslint](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-await-in-loop#:%7E:text=Disallow%20await%20inside%20of%20loops,parallelization%20benefits%20of%20async%20%2F%20await%20.) pinpoints your issue in a fairly good manner.

> Usually, the code should be refactored to create all the promises at
> once, then get access to the results using `Promise.all()`. Otherwise,
> each successive operation will not start until the previous one has
> completed.

Answer (score 0):

you are reciving a warn because you are running all the http calls in cascade and not in parallel, this is is very slow.
You can create an Array of Promises and then use Promise.All()

```js
const promises = urls.map(url => axios.get(url));
const response = await Promise.all(promises);
responseList.push(...response);
```